# How can I jump to next iteration starting from the inside of a given/when constuct?

Tags: perl, while-loop, switch-statement

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature "switch";
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  given ($_) {
    when ("abc" or "def") {
      # ...
      next;
    }
    when (/\w{3}/) {
      print $_;
      next;  
    }

}

__DATA__
abc
def
ghi
lmn
opq
rst
uvz
```

I'm having this output:

```
abc
def
ghi
lmn
opq
rst
uvz
```

but I want this one:

```
ghi
lmn
opq
rst
uvz
```

I don't know what I'm missing, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `given`/`when`. The smartmatch feature which it builds upon is a failure, and should be avoided. The correct way to write this is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if $_ eq 'abc' or $_ eq 'def';
    say $_;
}
```

But back to `given`/`when`. The `when ("abc" or "def")` condition is – for some reason – parsed as `when ("abc")` (verify this by running a script under `perl -MO=Deparse`). If you want to smartmatch against a set of values, use an array: `when (["abc", "def"])`.

That condition will still not match because `$_` is a string with a trailing newline. You need to `chomp` it first.

Of course, the `next` inside the `when` blocks is entirely unnecessary. Unlike in C's `switch`/`case`, there is no implicit fallthrough. To explicitly continue matching, one can use the `continue` command. So your code could be rewritten to:

```
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  given ($_) {
    when (["abc", "def"]) {
       # do nothing
    }
    when (/\w{3}/) {
      print "$_\n";
    }
  }
}
```

But let's assume it had been written

```
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  given ($_) {
    when (["abc", "def"]) {
       # do nothing
    }
    when (/\w{3}/) {
      print $_;
    }
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

So we would have to skip the `print "\n"`. In that case, we can use loop labels:

```
LINE:
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  given ($_) {
    when (["abc", "def"]) {
       next LINE;
    }
    when (/\w{3}/) {
      print $_;
    }
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Any loop control command like `next`, `redo`, `last`, `continue` can take a label to refer to some outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `given/when` is a bit troublesome and marked as experimental. There is some controversy around it. You can find out more about [the experimental details here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when).

In your context, you can use `break` to break out of the enclosing given block

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature "switch";

while (<DATA>) {
    given ($_) {
        break when (["abc\n","def\n"]);
        when(/\w{3}/) {
            print $_;
            break;
        }
    }
};

__DATA__
abc
def
ghi
lmn
opq
rst
uvz
```

Comment: Perl has a `break` keyword starting with version 5.16   "Under the "switch" feature, Perl gains the experimental keywords given , when , default , continue, and break . Starting from Perl 5.16, one can prefix the switch keywords with CORE:: to access the feature without a use feature statement"

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten the details of given/when after years of avoidance